Is it possible to create a "button" inside an XCOS diagram in order to print automatically a curve defined by a "To Workspace" block?
In XCOS, plot curves are basic. So, I am using the "To Workspace" functionality to improve prints with a script I run in SCILAB console.
It is boring, so I wonder if there is a possibility to get that automatically from XCOS diagram with a kind of button or a macro?
I want to know if it is possible to create a button, or a macro, or a shortcut inside an XCOS diagram that print automatically a curve defined with a "To Workspace" block?
Today, I am using a script which performs the plot I want and "stored" in a text block placed in the XCOS diagram.
So, when I want to plot the desired curve, I launch the simulation, then, I copy the script in the SCILAB console to get the plot. It is working well but it is not very convenient. A kind of "macro button" should be an elegant answer to this question. And the best should be to add the simulation launching to the macro.

You should apply the "dual" approach, i.e. you should run your Xcos diagram from a Scilab script, where you can then apply any postprocessing to the data created by the ToWorkspace block. See https://help.scilab.org/docs/2024.1.0/en_US/scicos_simulate.html.
S.

Thank you very much Stéphane. I will try the dual approach.

OK, if you need further help you can also reach us at scilab.discourse.group

All right, with pleasure
